# Translate some bison2 code to bison3 #define YYPARSE_PARAM

Tags: bison

Never looked at bison before, and I'm trying to update a 4 y.o project to work on recent packages.
I've done some research that bison3 no longer uses the yyparse macro, but instead uses the %parse_param directive. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find an example of how to implement the %parse_param instead of using the YYPARSE macro.

```
%{
#define YYPARSE_PARAM yythd
#define YYLEX_PARAM yythd
#define YYTHD ((THD *) yythd)
```

Error when compiling is "error: 'yythd' was not declared in this scope #define YYTHD ((THD *) yythd)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where do you typedef `yythd`?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's a sql_yacc.yy file and the first lines of the file are the defines stated above. Is there anything specific u need me to look for?

Comment: If you are trying to compile mysql, then you should probably just find a newer source repository. There's a bug report which was resolved three years ago, afaik. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71250